# Disable "mobile phone" and "fax" from joomla contact information

Tags: forms, joomla, contacts

I have a Joomla installation with a contacts form. Specifically, there are two contacts with position, email, name, phone. However, Joomla seems to insist on having two empty columns "Mobile phone" and "Fax" that I can't seem to get rid of. Neither contact has a mobile phone or fax, and they are disabled in both sets of contact parameters?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "hide" for mobile phone and fax in your "Contacts" component instead of each contact.

Go to Components->Contacts->Contacts. Click on "Parameters" on component's toolbar and set everything to "hide".

[Parameters for Contacts Component http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/8296/parameters.png](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/8296/parameters.png)

...and come back here and tell us if it worked. By the way, I use a component named [QContacts](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/4811/details) that is more powerful than the official, including captcha support, custom fields, etc.

Comment: I had already done this - it didn't work. I'll look into QContacts, but I read that one should generally avoid 3rd party extensions at all costs.

Comment: The problem when using 3rd party extensions is about upgrading it along with new Joomla versions, but QContacts is based on Joomla's official Contact component, so the developers always try to keep it up to date with the Joomla official. I try to avoid 3rd party components when the core has all the features I need, but sometimes this isn't possible. Captcha support is one of the reasons I chose QContacts.

Comment: I guess I hadn't tried that because I just did that "again" and this time it worked. Assuming no voodoo it means I just screwed it up the first time ;)

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked! I had a similar problem before, so I always check my "global parameters".